# WordPress Login Disabled by ServInt

Tags: wordpress

I design and edit websites for another company, and their WordPress sites are stored on ServInt. While I wasn't the webmaster before, I have been given full control of the server from this point forwarded (meaning I have root access).  When trying to edit a WordPress page however, I keep getting this message "WordPress login has been disabled by ServInt."

Take a look here: http://superpestproducts.com/wp-admin/

Also, all the WordPress sites hosted there say the same thing when I try to access wp-admin.

I'm wondering why this is happening and how I can regain access to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have root access to the sites you can just search through the code for 'ServInt'. For example:

```
find /var/www/html -name "*.php"|xargs grep ServInt
```

Then disable the code that is generating that message. Or you can replace the affected files with the original source from WordPress.